# How do I cite work with its title and full information?

Tags: biblatex

I use biblatex for citation, and it provides things such as `\citetitle` and `\fullcite`. `\fullcite` is almost what I want, but it starts with the authors not with the title. `\citetitle` will only cite the title but not the other data of the record. Is there a way to fully cite a bibkey by title first:

"A novel approach...", F. Bar, B. Foo, In: "Novel Approaches of Novelty", 1656.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foobar.bib}
@article{foobar,
  author={Bar Foo and Foo Bar},
  title={A novel approach for citations},
  journal={FOOBAR},
  volume={23},
  year={2042},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{foobar.bib}

\begin{document}

This chapter is based on: \fullcite{foobar}\vspace{1cm}

This chapter is based on: \citetitle{foobar}\vspace{1cm}

But I still want to have it in normal mode as this \textcite{foobar}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which will render to the following:
[image]

What I want is, to keep the references (and bib-style) and textcites as they are, but to change `\fullcite{foobar}` to start with the title (or simulate this behaviour):

[image]

Comment: But you still want your bibliography to have the conventional order of "Author: Title ...", right? What `biblatex` style do you use? Would you mind creating a short MWE?

Comment: Yes you are right. Working on MWE right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be as easy as

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\bfullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
   \settoggle{blx@useauthor}{false}%
   \settoggle{blx@useeditor}{false}%
   \settoggle{blx@usetranslator}{false}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
```

We define a new command `\bfullcite` (of course you can overwrite `\fullcite`) and (locally and temporarily) toggle `useauthor`, `useeditor` and `usetranslator` to false, so their names appear after the title.

This however, may not give what you want with respect to editors' names, so we employ the following very ugly modification

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\bfullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
      \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{byeditorx}{%
    \ifnameundef{editora}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
       \newunit}%
    \ifnameundef{editorb}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditorb]{editorb}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editorb}{editor}%
       \newunit}%
    \ifnameundef{editorc}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditorc]{editorc}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editorc}{editor}%
       \newunit}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bytranslator}{%
    \ifnameundef{translator}
      {}
      {\printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \bibstring{bytranslator}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
       \clearname{editor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
       \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{translator}
      {}
      {\printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
       \clearname{translator}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{bytranslator+othersstrg}%
       \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{withothers}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
    \iffieldundef{#1type}
      {\bibstring{#2}}
      {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
         {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}
         {\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}}}
  \makeatletter
  \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{%
    \iffieldundef{editortype}
      {\def\abx@tempa{editor}}
      {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{editortype}}}%
    \let\abx@tempb=\empty
    \ifnamesequal{editor}{translator}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
       \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{translator}}}
      {}%
    \ifnamesequal{editor}{commentator}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
       \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{commentator}}}
      {\ifnamesequal{editor}{annotator}
         {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
          \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{annotator}}}
         {}}%
    \ifnamesequal{editor}{introduction}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
       \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{introduction}}}
      {\ifnamesequal{editor}{foreword}
         {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
          \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{foreword}}}
         {\ifnamesequal{editor}{afterword}
            {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
             \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{afterword}}}
            {}}}%
    \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
      {\printtext{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
      {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{%
    \def\abx@tempa{translator}%
    \ifnamesequal{translator}{commentator}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
       \clearname{commentator}}
      {\ifnamesequal{translator}{annotator}
         {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
          \clearname{annotator}}
         {}}%
    \ifnamesequal{translator}{introduction}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
       \clearname{introduction}}
      {\ifnamesequal{translator}{foreword}
         {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
          \clearname{foreword}}
         {\ifnamesequal{translator}{afterword}
            {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
             \clearname{afterword}}
            {}}}%
    \bibstring{\abx@tempa}}%
   \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
   \settoggle{blx@useauthor}{false}%
   \settoggle{blx@useeditor}{false}%
   \settoggle{blx@usetranslator}{false}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
```

in which the editor macros are made to print "Eddie Ditorm, ed." instead of "edited by Eddie Ditor".

MWE

```
\documentclass[british,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foobar,
  author={Bar Foo and Foo Bar},
  title={A novel approach for citations},
  journal={FOOBAR},
  volume={23},
  year={2042},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\bfullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
      \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{byeditorx}{%
    \ifnameundef{editora}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
       \newunit}%
    \ifnameundef{editorb}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditorb]{editorb}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editorb}{editor}%
       \newunit}%
    \ifnameundef{editorc}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditorc]{editorc}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editorc}{editor}%
       \newunit}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bytranslator}{%
    \ifnameundef{translator}
      {}
      {\printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \bibstring{bytranslator}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
       \clearname{editor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
       \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{translator}
      {}
      {\printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
       \clearname{translator}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{bytranslator+othersstrg}%
       \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{withothers}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
    \iffieldundef{#1type}
      {\bibstring{#2}}
      {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
         {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}
         {\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}}}
  \makeatletter
  \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{%
    \iffieldundef{editortype}
      {\def\abx@tempa{editor}}
      {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{editortype}}}%
    \let\abx@tempb=\empty
    \ifnamesequal{editor}{translator}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
       \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{translator}}}
      {}%
    \ifnamesequal{editor}{commentator}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
       \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{commentator}}}
      {\ifnamesequal{editor}{annotator}
         {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
          \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{annotator}}}
         {}}%
    \ifnamesequal{editor}{introduction}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
       \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{introduction}}}
      {\ifnamesequal{editor}{foreword}
         {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
          \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{foreword}}}
         {\ifnamesequal{editor}{afterword}
            {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
             \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{afterword}}}
            {}}}%
    \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
      {\printtext{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
      {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{%
    \def\abx@tempa{translator}%
    \ifnamesequal{translator}{commentator}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
       \clearname{commentator}}
      {\ifnamesequal{translator}{annotator}
         {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
          \clearname{annotator}}
         {}}%
    \ifnamesequal{translator}{introduction}
      {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
       \clearname{introduction}}
      {\ifnamesequal{translator}{foreword}
         {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
          \clearname{foreword}}
         {\ifnamesequal{translator}{afterword}
            {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
             \clearname{afterword}}
            {}}}%
    \bibstring{\abx@tempa}}%
   \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
   \settoggle{blx@useauthor}{false}%
   \settoggle{blx@useeditor}{false}%
   \settoggle{blx@usetranslator}{false}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \bfullcite{wilde}

  \bfullcite{foobar}

  \bfullcite{matuz:doody}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much esp. for taking care of the editor stuff, which indeed looks very complicated.

Comment: @math Well ... it certainly looks complicated (and is hideous), but maybe there is a short and sweet way to do it (there often is with `biblatex`) I'm not aware of.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't want to complain! I am very happy with it, as I would not be able to solve this by myself.